# BAT script To perform file compare & based on the result, to run IF or else step

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

Below are the two files:

A.txt

```
Ricky
Rose
Charles
```

PrevA.txt

```
Ricky
Rose
Charles
```

When I perform file comparison, after each line of compare, my below code runs for If statement. I need my code to execute either If or else step after full file comparison

Below is my code:

```
IF EXIST E:\INVdata\A.txt 
(FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (E:\INVdata\A.txt) DO 
(FOR /F "tokens=*" %%b IN (E:\INVdata\PrevA.txt) DO 
(IF %%a==%%b  
(DEL /Q E:\INVdata\A.txt) 
ELSE
(COPY E:\INVdata\A.txt 
 E:\INVdata\PrevA.txt))))
```

Comment: Read the help text appearing when you type `if /?` into a command prompt window; you will find the correct syntax of `if`/`else` blocks...

Comment: What is the purpose of all this? do you want to analyse the differences between the files, or do you just need to know whether or not they are equal? do you just want to know whether a file has been modified?

Comment: @aschipfl The purpose is like, I need my code to analyze the file contents for equality to perform if statement.. If not to perform else part

Comment: To simply check for equality, use `fc` which sets `ErrorLevel` in case of differences and clears it otherwise. If you basically want to detect whether a file has been modified, there are better methods (archive attibute, synchronisation options of `xcopy` or `robocopy`, etc.)...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if files are identical, then use a command that is designed to look for differences.

FC will return success if the files match, and error if there is a difference.

```
@echo off
pushd E:\INVdata
if exist A.txt fc A.txt PrevA.txt >nul && del A.txt || copy A.txt PrevA.txt
popd
```

Given that you delete A.txt if it is the same as PrevA.txt, then I suspect you also want to delete A.txt after you copy it when it differes from PrevA.txt. You can do that with one operation using MOVE instead of COPY.

```
@echo off
pushd E:\INVdata
if exist A.txt fc A.txt PrevA.txt >nul && del A.txt || move /y A.txt PrevA.txt
popd
```

You also might want to use the /B switch with FC, which will cause it to do a binary comparison.

Comment: Hi dbenham I'm never shure about the operator precendence with `&&` and `||` on the same line does the `||`act on a failing fc or failing del. Thats why my comment with suggesting fc uses parentheses with an exit.

Comment: @LotPings - `||` will fire if the last command in `&&` fails, but as far as I know, `DEL` never returns an error, even if it displays an error message, so the code I have shown should be safe. But if there is any doubt, you can add a command that is guaranteed to succeed. For example: `... &&(del A.txt&(call ))||copy A.txt PrevA.txt`

Comment: @dbenham could u plz tell me why the below has been used     :          &(call ))

Comment: `(CALL )` functions as a null operation that does nothing except set the ERRORLEVEL to 0. It guarantees that the `||` command(s) do not fire if the `DEL` fails with an error.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing anything here it is formatted in such a way as you can understand the correct use of parentheses:

```bat
IF EXIST E:\INVdata\A.txt (
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (E:\INVdata\A.txt) DO (
        FOR /F "tokens=*" %%b IN (E:\INVdata\PrevA.txt) DO (
            IF %%a==%%b (
                DEL /Q E:\INVdata\A.txt
            ) ELSE (
                COPY E:\INVdata\A.txt E:\INVdata\PrevA.txt
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Compo

Comment: plz share me is there any way to perform full file comparison, as I can't make use of too much of parenthesis in single argument to pass ,like as u specified above(CA workload scripting)

Comment: @Ragav It's unclear to me what you try to accomplish, your read each line of file A.txt in a loop then, when you have the first line start another loop which iterates through the lines of PrevA.txt - the first line of PrevA.txt matches and you DELETE the whole FILE A.txt ??? all other iterations and comparisons will fail!!! cause A.txt is gone.

Comment: @LotPings, you are right..I am juz asking is there any way to perform full comparison

Comment: *full file comparison

Comment: See `fc.exe /?` It will compare files and give an Errorlevel if they differ. `fc "E:\INVdata\A.txt" "E:\INVdata\PrevA.txt" && (Del "E:\INVdata\A.txt"&Exit /B 0)` Next Line `Copy "E:\INVdata\A.txt" "E:\INVdata\PrevA.txt"` HTH

Comment: @Lotpings I have the tried the above suggestion.. But during execution the file is not getting deleted when two text files had the same content.. Is there any guide lines on how to use FC command or Could you plz suggest any other solution which works for fill file comparison

Comment: Ragav it's very difficult to decide wether it doesn't function without seeing any real life samples of your data. fc will do a char for char comparison. Empty lines spaces at the end of line will have fc fail. Spreading details over several comments doesn't help US. Maybe a visual tool like WinMerge takes you further.

Answer (score 0):

Ragav you might be better off comparing the contents of the files in way similar to linux diff. With `findstr.exe /?`
See the following examples:

See content of both files

> type *A.txt

```
PrevA.txt


Ricky
old
Rose
Old
Charles

A.txt


Ricky
newa
Rose
NewB
Charles
```

See lines which are in both files

```
> findstr /i /G:A.txt PrevA.txt
Ricky
Rose
Charles
```

See lines only in PrevA.txt

```
> findstr /i /V /G:A.txt PrevA.txt
old
Old
```

See lines only in A.txt

```
> findstr /i /V /G:PrevA.txt A.txt
newa
NewB
```